minimum of decision variables not including zero. OR-Tools CP-SAT solver
I have a problem where I need to take the minimum of decision variables, but want to exclude variables which take a value of zero. For e.g. if variable values are : 0,0,2,5,7 then I want the minimum to be 2. I also have a corresponding boolean variable which is 1 when the variable value is > 0, else 0 (when variable = 0). Below is my attempt, but using the AddMinEquality of cpsat solver I get the overall minimum (expected) which is 0.
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

dvs = {}
for i in range(5):
    dvs[i] = model.NewIntVar(lb=0, ub=100, name = f"dv_{i}")
    
# creating bool vars which are tied to the above integer variables
bool_dvs = {i : model.NewBoolVar(f"bool_i") for i in range(5)}
model.Add(bool_dvs[0] + bool_dvs[1] == 0)
model.Add(bool_dvs[2] + bool_dvs[3] + bool_dvs[4] == 3)
    
# if bool_dvs = 0 then dvs = 0, else if bool_dvs = 1 then dvs > 0
for i in range(5):
    model.Add(dvs[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_dvs[i].Not())
    model.Add(dvs[i] > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_dvs[i])


# make the rest of the 3 to be different
model.add_all_different([dvs[2], dvs[3], dvs[4]])

# create a decision variable to hold the minimum of the decision variables
minimum_dv = model.NewIntVar(lb=0, ub=100, name = "minimum_dv")

model.AddMinEquality(minimum_dv, [dvs[i] for i in range(5)])

model.Minimize(sum(dvs[i] for i in range(5)))

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.solve(model)

print([solver.Value(dvs[i]) for i in range(5)])
print([solver.Value(bool_dvs[i]) for i in range(5)])
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 2]

print(solver.Value(minimum_dv))
# 0


from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

dvs = [model.NewIntVar(lb=0, ub=100, name = f"dv_{i}") for i in range(5)]
    
# creating bool vars which are tied to the above integer variables
bool_dvs = [model.NewBoolVar(f"bool_i") for i in range(5)]
proxy_dvs = [model.NewIntVar(lb=0, ub=100, name = f"P_dv_{i}") for i in range(5)]
    
# bool_dvs[i] <=> dvs[i] > 0`
# proxy_dvs[i] == bool_dvs ? dvs : 100
for i in range(5):
    model.Add(dvs[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_dvs[i].Not())
    model.Add(dvs[i] > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_dvs[i])
    model.Add(proxy_dvs[i] == 100).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_dvs[i].Not())
    model.Add(proxy_dvs[i] == dvs[i]).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_dvs[i])

# create a decision variable to hold the minimum of the decision variables
minimum_dv = model.NewIntVar(lb=0, ub=100, name = "minimum_dv")

model.AddMinEquality(minimum_dv, proxy_dvs)


Essentially, you want to take the minimum value when the boolean variable is 1. This can be achieved through the following constraints
# enforce minimum is greater than 0.
minimum_dv > 0

minimum_dv <= dv_value_i + big_M * (1 - bin_var_i) ; for all I
# when bin_var_i = 0 then the constraint is vacuous, when bin_var_i = 1,
# the constraint becomes active, and will ensure we take the minimum 
# value (where the boolean variable is 1). big_M could be max(dv_value_i)

Below is the code:
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

dvs = {}
for i in range(5):
    dvs[i] = model.NewIntVar(lb=0, ub=100, name = f"dv_{i}")
    
# creating bool vars which are tied to the above integer variables
bool_dvs = {i : model.NewBoolVar(f"bool_i") for i in range(5)}
model.Add(bool_dvs[0] + bool_dvs[1] == 0)
model.Add(bool_dvs[2] + bool_dvs[3] + bool_dvs[4] == 3)
    
# if bool_dvs = 0 then dvs = 0, else if bool_dvs = 1 then dvs > 0
for i in range(5):
    model.Add(dvs[i] == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_dvs[i].Not())
    model.Add(dvs[i] > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(bool_dvs[i])


# make the rest of the 3 to be different
model.add_all_different([dvs[2], dvs[3], dvs[4]])

# create a decision variable to hold the minimum of the decision variables
minimum_dv = model.NewIntVar(lb=0, ub=100, name = "minimum_dv")

# NOT REQUIRED
# model.AddMinEquality(minimum_dv, [dvs[i] for i in range(5)])

# minimum_dv <= dv_value_i + big_M * (1 - bin_var_i) ; for all i
for i in range(5):
    model.Add(minimum_dv <= dvs[i] + 200 * (1 - bool_dvs[i]))
model.Add(minimum_dv > 0)

model.Minimize(sum(dvs[i] for i in range(5)))

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.solve(model)

print([solver.Value(dvs[i]) for i in range(5)])
print([solver.Value(bool_dvs[i]) for i in range(5)])
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 2]

print(solver.Value(minimum_dv))
# 1


I do not get your solution.

So the idea is to pick the minimum value when the boolean flag = 1 and then disregard value = 0 (when boolean flag = 0). So I have put a constraint that minimum_dv > 0 and then the below constraint ensures that I pick minimum value (where boolean flag = 1), and then the constraint is vacuous (always satisfied) when boolean flag = 0.
minimum_dv > 0
minimum_dv <= dvs[i] + 100 * (1 - bool_dvs[i]) for all i
Might not be the most elegant / concise solution but seems to work. I get your solution though.
